# heroku restart bounce kills background workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque, restart

We have background (resque) jobs on heroku for our Ruby on Rails application.

When Heroku bounce the box as they did yesterday, our background jobs are lost.
Our background jobs run for about 2 - 6 hours.
Is there anyway to keep them running or restart them automatically after failure?

Answer (score 0):

In a nut shell, no, there's no easy way (if by easy you mean transparent to you, the app developer).

The best way to handle such interruptions is to properly save the job state on receipt of the [SIGTERM signal](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps#graceful_shutdown_with_sigterm) from the dyno manifold. Your worker dyno will be reconstituted in a different physical location where it can resume processing interrupted jobs.

While this involves extra development effort, the result is a more robust and resilient app (no matter what the underlying platform).